# Objdump: Retrieve flags

Tags: c, unix, bsd, objdump

I'm actually studying the unix objdump command.

I want to retrieve the flags showed by the command "objdump -f file"

Here is an example

> $>objdump -f /bin/ls
>
> /bin/ls:     file format elf64-x86-64 architecture: i386:x86-64, **flags 0x00000112:**
>
> **EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED**
>
> start address 0x0000000000404e68

I know that I can obtain 112 by making an | on the flags that are bitmasks defined in BSD lib.
The masks are:

> #define BFD_NO_FLAGS    0x00
>
> #define HAS_RELOC       0x01
>
> #define **EXEC_P**          0x02
>
> #define HAS_LINENO      0x04
>
> #define HAS_DEBUG       0x08
>
> #define **HAS_SYMS**        0x10
>
> #define HAS_LOCALS      0x20
>
> #define DYNAMIC         0x40
>
> #define WP_TEXT         0x80
>
> #define **D_PAGED**         0x100

---

Thanks to the elf struct and the e_type attribute I can obtain the HAS_RELOC flag and the EXEC_P flag.

How can I obtain the others?

Have I to retrieve 112 to get the flags or have I to retrieve the flags one by one? .

Comment: I don't understand this: `I want to retrieve the flags`. Can you explain what you're after? Are you writing a program to interact with `objdump` or are you just using it on the command line? You tagged the question C, but I don't see any C code besides the flag `define`s

Comment: If you're trying to check if a flag has been or'd into the 112, you can check it in c code by using binary "and". It will evaluate to true if the flags variable has that specific bit set: `if (HAS_SYMS & flags){ hasSyms=true; }`, you can check for each flag in this way

Comment: Hi, thanks you, I'm trying to recode the objdump command, that's why I've tagged C. I want to make the option -f.
I know that I can check if the flag is set by making a "&" like if 
 (HAS_SYMS & **flags**){ hasSyms=true; } but the mistake is that I didn't success to find the the "flags" that you are using to make the cmp. There is an attribute flag in the main elf structure that give me the main information about the elf file that I'm analysing. So I just want to retrieve the good flags variable.